# How to check file download status using javascript/JQuery at client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, download, status

User click on the button on the webpage to download the file, i want to track the file is being downloaded to the user machine or not using client side code like javascript/JQuery.

On button click, ASP.NET .ASHX Web handler code is called which return the file to be downloaded.

Also can we check using javascript/JQuery whether the user is having issue (security, firewall etc.) in downloading the file, when user click on the download button on the webpage.

Comment: Are you using AJAX for the file download?

Comment: We are not using Ajax

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via the "progress" event that is attached to an AJAX request.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("progress",event=>{
  console.log(`${event.loaded} out of ${event.total}`);
});
```

The download can then be handled via AJAX by creating a false link that links to the file data which will be saved in memory:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange(function(){
  if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
    //Download content via imaginary link with data saved in memory
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
    document.body.append(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }else if(this.status==404){
    console.error("page not found");
  }
});
xhr.open("GET","myfile.pdf",true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.send();
```